# Excluding .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .bmp in regular expression

Tags: javascript

I have written a regular expression in order to exclude .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .bmp from the text entry. But if I'm putting a.png it's not working.

Here is code:

```
  function isValidateName(e) {
      var filter = "^((?!.jpg)(?!.jpeg)(?!.png)(?!.bmp)[a-zA-Z0-9\\u00C0-\\u017F\\-\\.\\s\\'])";
      return String(e).search (filter) != -1;
  }

  alert(isValidateName("image.png")); // It's returning true
  alert(isValidateName(".png")); // It's returning false
```

Basically I want to restrict the user from putting .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .bmp at the end of the text.

Allow:

a png, a..png, a png., png .a etc

Restrict:
a.png, b.jpg

http://jsfiddle.net/RxwF8/3/

Could someone help me in this please !!

Answer (score 2):

Dot acts as a special character in regular expressions, which matches any character. So you must escape it to get rid of its special meaning: `\.`.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to check those extensions at the end of the string, then try this pattern:

```
  function isValidName(e) {
      return !(/\.(png|bmp|jpe?g)$/i).test(e);
  };
```

Test

```
  console.log(isValidName("myfile.png"))           // false
  console.log(isValidName("myfile.whatever.jPeG")) // false
  console.log(isValidName("myfile.gif"))           // true: this is valid
```

---

Note: the `/i` modifier at the end of the regular expression also checks for camelcase/mixedcase strings

Comment: Could you please modify the existing regular expression which I'm using because I don't know where to put this.

Comment: @user2080056 I've just rewritten your function.

Comment: But I have to match the rest all things as well like - [a-zA-Z0-9\\u00C0-\\u017F\\-\\.\\s\\']

Comment: It's working fine. But I need to combine this with the other things that is already there in the regular expression. Anyway thanks a lot for your quick support!!

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand: your question is *I want to restrict the user from putting .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .bmp at the end of the text.* Thus, what else you need to check?

Comment: Here is the regular expression. ^((?!.jpg)(?!.jpeg)(?!.png)(?!.bmp)[a-zA-Z0-9\\u00C0-\\u017F\\-\\.\\s\\']). Other than restricting the .jpg, .png etc I'm also checking for character & number entry.

Comment: Please let me know how can I combine the regex which you have created to restrict .jpg, .png along with what I have. I'm sorry If I'm asking more !!

Comment: the meaning of your character class is ONLY to ensure at least one character before the dot?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48582/discussion-between-user2080056-and-fabrizio-calderan)

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

```
/^[\u00C0-\u017Fa-z\d\s'.-]+\.(?!(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp)$)[a-z]+$/i
```